# Cloud Container Builder - gcloud app deploy fails with missing permission

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

I´m trying to setup a continuous deployment for an appengine application (standard environment) using Google Cloud Builder. I have the following cloudbuild.yaml setup:

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: ['app', 'deploy', 'frontend/app.yaml']
```

As I understand, the [cloud builder uses the service account](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/gcloud) [PROJECT-ID]@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com, therefore I added the role App Engine Admin in the IAM section of the cockpit. Still, it fails with the error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) You do not have permission to access app [...] (or it may not exist): Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
```

Any idea what i´m missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, the Container Builder service does not provide your build with the scopes necessary to do App Engine deployments. We are addressing this issue, and hope to have things working soon.

In the meantime, you can follow https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/issues/36 for updates.

Comment: Thank you, John. I´ll follow the github issue for updates!

Comment: The GitHub issue has now been resolved, so you should be able to get this working now.